# Jquery/Javascript ( Convert from ID to Class )

Tags: javascript, jquery

I did this script. But now i need to convert these id to classes because should I put it in other elements of the page.

## card ---> .card

## flip ---> .flip

```
 var init = function() {
      var card = document.getElementById('card');
      
      document.getElementById('flip').addEventListener( 'click', function(){
        card.toggleClassName('flipped');
      }, false);
    };
    
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
```

Can you help me?

SOLUTION :

```
$(function() {
  var card = $('.card');
  
  $('.flip').on( "click", function(){
    card.toggleClass('flipped');
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you defined the `toggleClassName` function anywhere? It's not standard. Also, it would be better to actually amend the HTML source directly to achieve this.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan #card.flipped { -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have tagged with [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), I would give this:

```
// Once document is loaded,
$(function () {
  // Change all the `#card`, `#flip` to classes:
  $("#card, #flip").addClass(function () { return this.id; }).removeAttr("id");
});
```

First it selects all the `#card` and `#flip`, there should be only 2 elements. It adds their respective `id` as `class` and removes the `id` attribute.

**Snippet**

```js
// Once document is loaded,
$(function () {
  // Change all the `#card`, `#flip` to classes:
  $("#card, #flip").addClass(function () { return this.id; }).removeAttr("id");
});
```

```css
.card {background: #f99;}
.flip {background: #9f9;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="card">Card</div>
<div id="flip">Flip</div>
```

If you just wanna add the extra classes, then you can use this:

```
$(function() {
  var card = $('.card');

  $('.flip').on( "click", function(){
    card.toggleClass('flipped');
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Dont work. This is effect of my code. https://gyazo.com/dcd3eac86eb840c6a12ef77683fd9621

Comment: @Master-Antonio Show your code! Not some image. Did you see my code in the answer?

Comment: @Master-Antonio Yes, if you wanna add and remove class, you can use jQuery's [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass), but your question was converting the `ID` to `class` right?

Comment: @Master-Antonio What does this mean? `#card ---> .card`,
`#flip ---> .flip`?

Comment: That id "card" and "flip" becomes classes. Sorry for my english.

Comment: @Master-Antonio I have added the solution. See above. `:)`

Comment: @Master-Antonio Thanks! `:)`